# no root shell freely available sudoers policies

Tags: security, sudo

I want to prevent users who need escalated privileges from obtaining any kind of a root shell. However since there are many ways to attain this, and many non root commands ( like those found in coreutils ) I'm wondering if there are any downloadable sudoers policies that provide restrictive access.

Comment: What is the difference between them having a shell and just using sudo to execute the commands?  You can give them access to only a certain command (or, I believe, a list), is that what you want?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand what you're asking. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Are there any special programs that give you headaches?

Comment: The only safe `sudoers` is an empty `sudoers`. By default, assume that any command has a shell escape. Running a specific command with escalated privileges corresponds to exceptional needs, and you need to study each exception. I don't understand what you're after: a list of safe commands? That doesn't exist; the vast majority of safe commands are useless.

Comment: I want to know if there are any downloadable policies that provide a list of common shell programs that do not provide a shell themselves so to speak. I'm basically looking for a preexisting security policy, though such a thing may not exist in any distributable form (outside of the default sample)

Answer (score 1):

## sudo

### overview

sudo allows you to give users and groups super user privileges.  sudo's configuration file can be found at **/etc/sudoers**.  Typically, one edits the sudoers file using the command **visudo**.  By default on *most* distributions, either no user is given sudo privileges, or the first user created is given such privileges.  **After that, users are typically created without sudo privileges.**

### flexibility

sudo allows you to give each user different settings, or even apply settings to groups of users.  For example, you could give the user *admin* or the group *admins* access to gain super user privileges.

You can also allow these users access to **specific programs**.  For example, you can give *Bob* sudo access to *apt-get* if you trust Bob to install packages and update packages on your system.

Your system most likely has a sudoers file, in which case you can open the file and see the examples provided.  I will show you an example here that might clear things up:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This gives any user in the group of *sudo* privileges to run any command anywhere without prompting for a password.  The user must first authenticate (ie: login), but once that happens, these users will have root access to the machine.

### tl;dr

Most distributions give the initial user sudo access, but users created thereafter are not given such access.  You can verify this by viewing **/etc/sudoers**.  Simply make sure users have no access to sudo via sudoers file to ensure no user can gain root shell via sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. However, if you grant some user root permissions (through sudo or whatever) to execute a program and that this program happens to provide access to a shell with these same permissions, you can't do anything against it.

When you give some permissions to execute a specific program you have to trust the program for not messing up (except, of course, if you really trust the user).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
username  ALL = ALL, !/bin/sh, !/bin/bash, !/bin/tcsh, !/bin/csh, !/bin/ksh, !/bin/zsh, !/bin/su
```

Comment: essentially, though more comprehensive

Comment: You forgot shutdown, halt, mkfs, dd... IMO there is **no secure way** maintaining a blacklist of possible dangerous programs. Go with a whitelist instead and think very hard why you would want users to have root-privileges in the first place.

Comment: @xenoterracide: +1 for Alex. There is no secure way to maintain a blacklist. A user can always `cp /bin/sh ~/not_a_shell ; sudo ~/not_a_shell` or `sudo ex +':!/bin/sh'`. Rather than trying to make it impossible, provide a supported/approved way that will audit and make people justify any elevation to full root.

Comment: well this is why I was asking if there are any downloadable policies... obviously publicly audited tools/policies are more secure than me or someone just coming up with them myself.